# Windows 8 app tile clock with seconds

Tags: windows, live, clock, tile

I want to develop an Windows 8 app that displays clock running with seconds in the tile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible if your app is not running, even with the background task refresh frequency is 15 minutes.

For now this scenario is simply not supported.